# how to print the first lines of a large XML?

Tags: python, xml

I have this large `XML` file on my drive. The file is too large to be opened with `sublimetext` or other text editors.

It is also too large to be loaded in memory by the regular `XML` parsers.

Therefore, I dont even know what's inside of it!

Is it just possible to "print" a few rows of the XML files (as if it was some sort of text document) so that I have an idea of the nodes/content?

I am suprised not to find an easy solution to that issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple ideas:

```
# print first 10 lines
with open('myfile.xml') as f:
    for x in range(10):
        print(f.readline().strip())

# print first 1000 bytes
with open('myfile.xml') as f:
    print(f.read(1000))
```

Comment: interestingly these solution seem to fail likely because the full XML is parsed as the first line...

Comment: @ℕʘʘḆḽḘ that is why I included the "1000 bytes" approach, as it doesn't use lines splitting

Comment: ha!! very smart! can you give a bit more background here? how many characters are equivalent to 1000 bytes? this works!! I thought f.read() would only read row by row!

Comment: 1000 bytes are roughly 1000 characters... depending on encoding it can be a bit less...

Answer (score 1):

This might help. Reading the first 10 lines

**Demo:**

```
c = 0
with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if c == 10:
            break
        print(line)
        c += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the few things I ever do on the command line: the "more" command is your friend. Just type

> more big.xml

Comment: won't work. All the file contents are in a single line.

Comment: The question asked for "the first lines" so it's reasonable to assume there is more than one. Downvoting an answer because it doesn't take account of information that's not available in the question is highly inappropriate.